# Change pitch of multiple audio files with SoX

Tags: audio, frequency, sox, pitch

I am intending to take my entire music collection and change the pitch from the original recorded a = 440 Hz to the more natural sounding/feeling a = 432 Hz.

For those of you who are not familiar with this concept, or the "why" for doing this, I highly encourage you to do a google search and see what it's all about.
But that is not entirely relevant.

I understand that I could even take [Audacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)) and one-by-one, convert and reexport the files with the new pitch. I have tried this and yes, it does work. However, my collection is quite large, and I was excited to find are more fitting command-line option, [SoX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX). How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
sox your_440Hz_music_file.wav your_432Hz_music_file.wav pitch -31
```

Comment: Wrong.  sox's "pitch" filter is in cents, but the poster's numbers are in Hertz.

Answer (score 3):

SoX's pitch filter only accepts 'cents' (100th of a semitone), so you have to calculate the distance between 432 Hz and 440 Hz in 'cents'. This involves the following logarithmic calculation:

```
2x/12 = 432/440
x/12 = log(432/440) / log(2)
   x = log(432/440) / log(2) * 12
   x = -0.3176665363342927165015877324608 semitones
   x = -31.76665363342927165015877324608 'cents'
```

So this SoX command should work:

```
sox input.wav output.wav pitch -31.76665363342927165015877324608
```

---

For those interested; this can also be done with SoX's open-source counterpart [FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "asetrate=44100*432/440,aresample=44100,atempo=440/432" output.wav
```

Or if FFmpeg is compiled with the Rubberband library:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "rubberband=pitch=432/440" output.wav
```