# How to warp/shift a pitch so I can hear a bat

Tags: audio, sox, pitch

I am looking for a way to "hear" a bat.
I have a 192khz sound recording of a bat and want to hear it. So "transform" it into a 0-12kHz recording?

I saw what I thought might be similar:
[change pitch of multiple audio files with Sox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736637/change-pitch-of-multiple-audio-files-with-sox/67449654#67449654)

And tried using something like:
log(12/192)  * log(2) * 1200  == 4800

`sox 331817.flac 331817_warp.wav pitch -4800`

You can see the whole spectrogram here:(192Khz)

`sox 331817.flac -n  rate 192.0k spectrogram -l -m -X 160 -z 95 -Z 0 -r -Y 257 -o spectro.png`

[image]

You can see my warped spectro here:

`sox 331817_warp.wav -n  rate 12.0k spectrogram -l -m -X 160 -z 95 -Z 0 -r -Y 257 -o spectro_warp.png`

[image]

Here's a video which encouraged me its possible:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJOloliWvB8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `speed -4800c`; it lowers both pitch and tempo. This is the least intrusive way of lowering pitch as it does not need to resample the sound. It will make the entire sound fragment a factor 16 longer, so take your time listening to it. Trim it down if possible; I suspect this is also what they did in the video.

Keep in mind that even a sample rate of 192 kHz may not be enough to accurately capture the full spectrum of a bat's voice. [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) is half of the sample rate; any audio above 96 kHz will be distorted. No post-processing is going to fix that.